# getting error while loading tensorflow models in cv.dnn.readnetfromtensorflow

Tags: opencv, tensorflow

I am getting the error like this
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.1) /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_importer.cpp:577: error: (-2:Unspecified error) Const input blob for weights not found in function 'getConstBlob

i am tried the graph generated by tf_text_graph.py and load the both .pb file and .pbtxt file to the cv.dnn.readfromtensorflow method but it gives the above error

```
blob = cv.dnn.blobFromImage(face, 1.0, (227, 227), MODEL_MEAN_VALUES, swapRB=False)
genderNet.setInput(blob)
genderPreds = genderNet.forward()
gender = genderList[genderPreds[0].argmax()]
# print("Gender Output : {}".format(genderPreds))
print("Gender : {}, conf = {:.3f}".format(gender, genderPreds[0].max()))
```

Comment: thanks in advance if any one answer my question

Comment: and the models format are

Comment: genderNet = cv.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(frozen_inference_graph.pb,graph.pbtxt )